# surfaceview can not be created in a popupwindow

Tags: android, surfaceview, popupwindow

I want to created a surfaceview in a popupwindow, but the surfacecreated method is not called. I put the surfaceview`s resource in the popupwindow`s XML, and in java code I called the surfaceview. 
The surfaceview is a childview for the popupwindow, but when I init it and call, the surfacecreated is not called how do I fix it? thanks!